# Rails select Tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to show a gender model with a select tags. Here my models

```
Customer        Gender
ID              Id
First           Customer_id
Last            description
Email
Password

Customer
  has_one :gender
Gender
  belongs_to :customer
```

Here my select tags atm

```
<%= collection_select(:gender, :id, Gender.all, :id, :description) %>
```

But its showing me the following error instead

```
NoMethodError in Customers#edit

Showing /home/jean/rail/map/app/views/customers/_general.html.erb where line #23 raised:

undefined method `id' for []:Array
Extracted source (around line #23):

20:     
21:     <%= #collection_select(:gender, :description, @genders, :id, :description)
22:     %>
23:     <%= collection_select(:gender, :id, Gender.all, :id, :description) %>
24: 
25:     <div class="customer_edit_name">
26:             <%= f.label "Birthday" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that you are trying to add a checkbox of Gender in customer form. If so it should be as

> collection_select(:customer, :gender_id, Gender.all, :id,
>   :description)